# What is the proper way to call an async method containing a loop without blocking the UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm

I have the below code when run blocks the UI from updating.

The ProcessDocumentRange method’s job is to loop through a range and call the BuildDocumentList method to add a document reference to List for each iteration of the loop.

```
 public List<Document> _queuedDocuments = new List<Document>();
 public string _instID = "";        
 static String _dest = "c:\\test";
 static Int32 _startId = 50001;
 static Int32 _endId = 65001;
```

```
private async void _btnStartClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await ProcessRecords();
}
```

```
private async Task ProcessRecords()
{
    // Call to Method which freezes UI
    await ProcessDocumentRange(_startId, _dest);
}
```

```
public async Task ProcessDocumentRange(int _startID, string _root)
{
    int year = 28;
    for (int i = _startID; i < _endId; i++) //Start of loop that freezes UI
    {
        _instID = year.ToString() + i.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
        await BuildDocumentList(year, i, _instID, _root);
    }
}
```

```
private async Task BuildDocumentList(int year, int image, string instID, string root)
{
    string documentIndexFile = root + year.ToString() + "\\" + instID + ".txt";

    if (!File.Exists(documentIndexFile))
        _queuedDocuments.Add(new Document { Year = year, Image = image });
}
```

I have tried calling the Method like the following and the UI doesn't freeze, but the loop exits and never builds the list: `await Task.Run(() => ProcessDocumentRange(_startId, _dest));`

Any help would b greatly appreciated.

Update to code that now throws Exception: "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."

```cs
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<Document> _queuedDocuments = new List<Document>();
```

```cs
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _tbURL.Text = _url;
            _tbDest.Text = _dest;
            _tbStartId.Text = _startId.ToString();
            _tbEndID.Text = _endId.ToString();
        }
```

```cs
        private async void _btnStartClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await ProcessDocumentRange(_startId, _dest);
        }
```

```cs
        public async Task ProcessDocumentRange(int _startID, string _root)
        {
            //Exception thrown at await Task.Run below.
            //Exception may have something to do with adding an item to the list
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int year = 28;
                for (int i = _startID; i < _endId; i++)
                {
                    _instID = year.ToString() + i.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
                    BuildDocumentList(year, i, _instID, _root);

                }
            });
        }
```

```cs
        private void BuildDocumentList(int year, int image, string instID, string root)
        {
            string documentIndexFile = root + year.ToString() + "\\" + instID + ".txt";

            if (!File.Exists(documentIndexFile))
                _queuedDocuments.Add(new Document { Year = year, Image = image });
        }
```

```cs
//Document Class
    public class Document : MainWindow
    {        
        private int _year = -1;
        public int Year
        {
            get
            {
                return _year;
            }
            set
            {
                _year = value;
            }
        }


        private int _image = -1;
        public int Image
        {
            get
            {
                return _image;
            }
            set
            {
                _image = value;
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: "the loop exits and never builds the list" how do you know it doesn't? You are not doing anything with the list. And how do you even know the loop exits, are you debugging the loop?

Comment: Yes, debugging. I have a watch setup and can see the count increase along with the process memory increasing as the loop progresses. All this happens while the UI is unresponsive. So really, the loop is working, but I can't figure out how to let it run without blocking the UI.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Task asynchronous programming model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/task-asynchronous-programming-model)

Comment: Make your task.run return data so you can do var mylist = await ...

Comment: See blurimage here https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-task-run-async-await for one way to do this. Once the list is returned you've done your expensive processing and it's results are on your UI thread.

Comment: Can you please post your non-freezing version that fails to populate the list? It should work.

Comment: By the way, I hope you understand that your posted code is executed synchronously? You never return any Task that could be awaited. This is why your loop freezes the UI (by exhausting the UI thread).

Comment: There are 2 changes to the above code which will keep the UI responsive, but the loop never succeeds in adding items to the list. 1st change is calling the ProcessDocumentRange "await Task.Run(() => ProcessDocumentRange(_startId, _dest));" Then I remove the await from "BuildDocumentList(year, i, _instID, _root);" in the ProcessDocumentRange method.

Comment: @BionicCode I'm new to working with async, but I had an idea that my method is still running on the UI thread, which is why it's freezing. Any suggestions on how to run the loop asynchronously?

Comment: @Andy I changed the method "ProcessDocumentRange" to a type of Task<List> and returned the list it created to var mylist = await... as you suggested, but the UI is still being blocked.

Comment: You should really try to follow the C# naming convention. PascalCase for method names. No leading underscore for parameter names (underscore is only used for fields). Add `Async` suffix to names of asynchronous methods (`DoSomethingAsync()`). Following conventions helps other programmers to understand your code easier (even if this means that you have to learn multiple conventions for each language you know).

Comment: [C# Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions), [Naming guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methods are executing synchronously because non of them returns an actual `Task`. But most important, you failed to reach your goal because you did not off-load the CPU intensive work to relief the UI thread. It's the loop that still exhausts the UI thread and therefore freezes the UI.
To move it to a different thread, a background thread, you must call `Task.Run`:

```cs
private async void _btnStartClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Call to Method which no longer freezes the UI.
  // Use await to wait asynchronously for the method to return
  await ProcessDocumentRangeAsync(_startId, _dest);

  // TODO::Do something with the populated list
}

public async Task ProcessDocumentRangeAsync(int startID, string root)
{
  // Execute loop on a background thread
  await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    int year = 28;
    for (int i = startID; i < _endId; i++)
    {
      _instID = year.ToString() + i.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
      BuildDocumentList(year, i, _instID, root);
    }
  });
}

private BuildDocumentList(int year, int image, string instID, string root)
{
  string documentIndexFile = root + year.ToString() + "\\" + instID + ".txt";
  if (File.Exists(documentIndexFile))
  {
    return;
  }

  // Because Document extends MainWindow, 
  // we must create the instance on the original Dispatcher thread (UI thread).
  // This is required because MainWindow inherits the DispatcherObject from Window.  
  // DispatcherObject instances have thread affinity (Dispatcher affinity).
  // Creating them on or accessing them from a thread that is not the associated Dispatcher thread
  // will throw a cross-thread exception (InvalidOperationException).
  // To solve this, we must execute the instantiation on the Dispatcher thread using the Dispatcher.
  // We use DispatcherPriority.Background to prevent the loop from exhausting the UI thread.
  // We could improve the performance if we could get rid of the Dispatcher.Invoke,
  // for example by avoiding making Document a Window. 
  // Instead it should be a simple data model (and not a control).
  this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
    () => CreateDocument(year, image), 
    DispatcherPriority.Background);
}

private void CreateDocument(int year, int image)
{
  var newDocument = new Document { Year = year, Image = image };
  _queuedDocuments.Add(newDocument);
}
```

If you don't have anything to do after the list is populated, you don't have to use `await`. Simply create the background thread and return to the UI thread and continue:

```cs
private async void _btnStartClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Call to Method which no longer freezes the UI.
  // Because of we don't await anything here 
  // the method is a pure concurrent method and we can 
  // immediately continue to do work on the current thread.
  ProcessDocumentRange(_startId, _dest);

  // TODO::The list is not populated at this point. 
  // The operation is still executing in parallel-
}

public void ProcessDocumentRange(int startID, string root)
{
  // Execute loop concurrently on a background thread 
  // and return immediately to the caller (click handler) 
  Task.Run(() =>
  {
    int year = 28;
    for (int i = startID; i < _endId; i++)
    {
      _instID = year.ToString() + i.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
      BuildDocumentList(year, i, _instID, root);
    }
  });
}

private BuildDocumentList(int year, int image, string instID, string root)
{
  string documentIndexFile = root + year.ToString() + "\\" + instID + ".txt";
  if (File.Exists(documentIndexFile))
  {
    return;
  }

  // Because Document extends MainWindow, 
  // we must create the instance on the original Dispatcher thread (UI thread).
  // This is required because MainWindow inherits the DispatcherObject from Window.  
  // DispatcherObject instances have thread affinity (Dispatcher affinity).
  // Creating them on or accessing them from a thread that is not the associated Dispatcher thread
  // will throw a cross-thread exception (InvalidOperationException).
  // To solve this, we must execute the instantiation on the Dispatcher thread using the Dispatcher.
  // We use DispatcherPriority.Background to prevent the loop from exhausting the UI thread.
  // We could improve the performance if we could get rid of the Dispatcher.Invoke,
  // for example by avoiding making Document a Window. 
  // Instead it should be a simple data model (and not a control).
  this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
    () => CreateDocument(year, image), 
    DispatcherPriority.Background);
}

private void CreateDocument(int year, int image)
{
  var newDocument = new Document { Year = year, Image = image };
  _queuedDocuments.Add(newDocument);
}
```

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions and hit a System.InvalidOperationException error. The message is "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this." Any thoughts as to why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Then you missed to show some relevant code. What are you doing with the collection, do you use it in the UI?

Comment: The collection is not being used in the UI. The BuildDocumentList method is just adding items to the collection. I do have the collection "public List<Document> _queuedDocuments = new List<Document>();" as a global in the MainWindow Class. At the point of error, I haven't accessed the collection other than trying to add items to it.

Comment: Can you please update your question and show the latest version of your complete code? That shows what you are doing when handling the click event? There must be some line where you update the UI or a property that binds to a control. I need to review it in order to tell you what is wrong. The above code definitely won't produce a cross thread exception.

Comment: Thank you. If that on purpose that Document is a Window? That's the reason for the exception, because you can't create a Window instance in the background thread. Why have you made Document a Window?

Comment: Document is even a MainWindow? Is that a typo?

Comment: I have updated the answer to adjust to the new information. But you must know that a `MainWindow` is a `Window` and `Window` is a very heavy class. In your code you are  creating 15k instances of `Window`! If the idea is to show each ´Document` in a dedicated `Window` you should make `Document` a simple data class. Then when you want to show it, you create a `MainWindow` instance, assign the `Document` that it hosts and show it. This way you only create the exact number of `MainWindow` instances that are really needed.

Comment: You even should consider to create a new `Window` e.g. `DocumentHost` instead of using the `MainWindow`. Deriving `Document` from `MainWindow` looks very wrong, but I don't know what you are doing. *Maybe* you have a good reason. But I doubt it.

Comment: I'm not creating a Window with the Document. The UI only has a few text blocks for variable input, a progress bar with nothing coded to it yet, a button tied to the button click event and a textbox to update the UI with some text every now an then. The methods that I'm calling don't even call the UpdateStatus Method that I created. If you think running this code in the MainWindow : Window class is causing this Issue. I can certainly break this out into another class. I was not aware that Window had so much significance and overhead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253535/discussion-between-bradg-and-bioniccode).

Comment: @BradG I have answered your latest question.